Standard error in two-sample T-test
Reviewing T-test basics and from a book (Hypothesis Testing, Jim Frost) the following plot is displayed.
group, mean, std, se mean, N
_____,_____,____,________,__
A,    97.0, 10.3, 2.66,   15
B,    107.8,13.2, 3.42,   15 

.95 diff CI, T-val, P-val
___________, _____, _____
-16.9, -4.5, -3.7,  0.002

In this two sample T-test I see that there are both standard deviations and standard errors around the means. I haven't noticed what software the author is using, so this is a general question. In most software implementations, how is the sample's se mean computed?
My naive guess is bootstrap sampling then take std(array_bootstrap_means). Is this correct? If so, how is N units selected, is w/ replacement enabled or disabled?

Hint: $(10.3/2.66)^2=(13.2/3.42)^2=15.$

Expanding, $se = \sqrt{ \frac{ \sum (x_i - \bar{x} ) ^2}{N^2} }$

Probably not, because most software will use the bias-corrected estimate of the SD.  But you can readily check by supplying a tiny dataset to the software and comparing its output to your manual calculations.
